# How can I get placeholder padding to work properly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, placeholder

When trying to style a placeholder I ran across unexpected behavior on IE.

Playing around it seemed that **the padding meant for the placeholder alone, affected the whole input element**. Same with `margin`.

Any reasonable workaround?

**Edit** The code is actually in a mixin which is used by multiple `input`s. I can't just hardcode the value, it needs to be relative to original.

```css
input {
   padding: 5px 72px;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 0%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 28%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 72%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 100%);
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}
 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 15px;
 }
 input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 15px;
 }
```

```html
<input placeholder="mandatory" />
```

Comment: For your response to my now-deleted answer: "It's actually in a less mixin. I don't initially know the values on the input itself": you'd receive better answers if you tagged this as LESS and provided your LESS code instead.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, but it's a use case. The question is to generally set a relative padding on the placeholder.